# how to get file extension when extension not present in filename?

Tags: android, file

In my android application I let user select file from device and upload it to server. One issue I am facing now is in some devices, filenames dont have extension present. Due to this i cam unable to get extension of file using neither index of last "." approach nor URI approach. How can I solve this issue? Please help.

Comment: You should rely on the mime type instead. https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info#:~:text=Retrieve%20a%20file's%20MIME%20type,-A%20file's%20data&text=To%20get%20the%20data%20type,type%20from%20its%20filename%20extension.

Comment: already tried, didnt work

Comment: If the filename does not end with an extension then there is no extension. Why dont you accept that?

Comment: You forgot to tell that nowadays picking a file does not deliver a filename too. You have to query that name using the obtained uri.

Comment: @blackapps there can be files without extension in the end of filename. In some devices it will be treated as BIN file, but in some other devices it works fine.

Comment: @r2b2 android official documentation code did nt work initially in the devices where the file was being treated as BIN file. But in devices which are treating this file as a proper one, that code works.

Comment: Of course there can be file names without extension. Who said there can not? And i have no idea what you consider to be a bin file. And why do you need an extension if you upload a file to a server. The last one that needs an extension to handle a file would be a server. And devices dont handle files but apps. And every app can do it in its own way.